# 1 digit year into datetime(YYYY) year

Tags: python, datetime

I have a mixed date data.
For example : 11-DEC and 7-DEC in which 11 and 7 are the years.
When I am converting into datetime by using `strptime()` by passing `%y-%b`. I am getting this error:

> error: time data '9-Dec' does not match format '%y-%b'.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't see a "two digit year without zero-padding" code in [the datetime format code table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), so I don't think this behavior is possible out of the box. You may need to write your own parsing logic.

Comment: from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) - '%y - Year without century as a **zero-padded** decimal number.'

Comment: Hi @Kevin , I am not able create a parsing logic here. I have tried to use str.zipfill() but that doesn't work. Can you help me out?